# Does MFC have a built in grid control?

Tags: mfc, custom-controls

First what I want: The ability to display a grid with multiple columns, each cell having a custom render callback. So you might use such a control to display your inventory in a game, or something like the behaviour in Google Chrome where it shows a grid of popular pages you visit.

I've been playing with `CListCtrl` and while I can get custom rendering ability on each item, I can't get it work with columns - having say 3 items per row. The control has column-related methods but I think these are specifically for the built-in functionality where different attributes of an item are shown automatically in each column... not for providing a generic grid control.

So, does such functionality exist in MFC? If not then I wonder if the easiest approach is for me to actually insert each of the rows as an Item... and then the custom rendering draws the multiple cells in the row, I could also do custom UI to support clicking on the cells.

But what I really want is to be able to create a custom control, and add this as an item to a list - like in Flex for instance - so I/O etc is automatically handled.

Any advice/information welcome...

Answer (score 12):

[Dundas](http://www.dundas.com) has thrown some of its (excellent) components in the public domain. Their [Ultimate Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateGrid.aspx) is available on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateGrid.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a built-in control, but I think you should take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gridctrl.aspx).
The article is describing in detail the functionality of a fully featured MFC grid control, derived from CWnd, for displaying tabular data.

Comment: I have come across that control; it seems it probably does what's wanted but it might be a struggle getting it into our project.

Comment: I use this in a commercial app. Deployment is easy. There were a few subtle edge-case bugs we had to fix. Overall a great control and completely customizable - you have the source.

Answer (score 2):

`YOUR_LIST_CONTROL.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT|LVS_EX_INFOTIP|LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);`

I think it will help you ([`SetExtendedStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=msvc-170#setextendedstyle)).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this one:
https://code.google.com/p/cgridlistctrlex/
very complete